# Jenkins: separator parameter with declarative syntax pipeline (multibranch pipeline) job

Tags: jenkins, syntax, pipeline, dsl, separator

I am using declarative syntax "Jenkinsfile" pipeline syntax and want to separate my parameters into groups. I found articles that show I can use the separator plugin with something like:

```
String sectionHeaderStyleCss = ' color: white; background: green; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important; padding: 5px; text-align: center; '
String separatorStyleCss = ' border: 0; border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; background: #999; '

pipeline
{
  parameters
  {
    separator(
      name: "Group_1",
      sectionHeader: "Foo Params",
      separatorStyle: separatorStyleCss,
      sectionHeaderStyle: sectionHeaderStyleCss
    )
    string(
      name: 'FooStuff',
      defaultValue: 'Foo',
      description: 'Foo Stuff',
    )
    separator(
      name: "Group_2",
      sectionHeader: "Bar Params",
      separatorStyle: separatorStyleCss,
      sectionHeaderStyle: sectionHeaderStyleCss
    )
    string(
      name: 'BarStuff',
      defaultValue: 'Bar',
      description: 'Bar Stuff'
    )
  }
}
```

when I open 'Build with Parameters' in Jenkins the first time its fine I see the layout I expect with :

```
+----- Foo Params -----+
FooStuff: Foo
+----- Bar Params -----+
BarStuff: Bar
```

but if I open 'Build with Parameters again... it seems like the separators multiply like Mickey Mouse brooms and now I have:

```
+----- Foo Params -----+
FooStuff: Foo
+----- Bar Params -----+
BarStuff: Bar
+----- Foo Params -----+
+----- Bar Params -----+
```

Does anyone know why my parameters are multiplying each time I run?

Comment: can you add link of the plugin you are using

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameter-separator

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as you in my pipeline and it's working as expected, nothing is being repeated.
I'm using 1.3 version of Parameter Separator Plugin

Comment: this looks like a comment